# Why can our Web Front Ends not browse the site?

Tags: 2013, front-end, filenotfoundexception

We have recently set up our SharePoint 2013 environment.  We have a Central Admin server and 2 load balanced Web Front Ends (the load balancing might not be fully set up yet though).

On the Central Admin server, we can go in IIS and click Browse to see

```
https://localhost/Pages/Default.aspx.
```

It loads without any problem.  On both of the web front ends, if we do the same thing, we get *Sorry, something went wrong*.  **File Not Found**

The logs aren't helpful either...they just show FileNotFoundExceptions.

Any ideas what could be wrong with our setup?  Let me know of any additional information that may be helpful.

Comment: may be problem with connections, u can check all connections relating to the WFEs.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

Make sure you add the URLs of your web front-ends (http...myfrontend1)(http...myfrontend2) to the intranet zone of your webapp in Alternate Access Mappings.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT  (Previous Redacted)**

If it's working on your first server (central admin), that is at least a good sign.  I would try these things:

1. Re-Run Configuration Manager
2. If #1 didn't work, run it again, and remove the server from the farm, then re-join server.
3. Are all these servers in the same OU.  If after rerunning the configuration wizard it works, and then again does not work, check your group policies (see last item as well to track down the particular issue)
4. Make sure you have added your addresses to the loopback check.

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0\BackConnectionHostNames.

Finally, if all this fails or in Tandem with above:

Load up [ProcMon](http://live.sysinternals.com/Procmon.exe) and [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/get-fiddler) to watch the activity on the host when you try to open the web page.  Be sure to first add URL to hosts file so the server hits itself (ProcMon is only monitoring local instance).  From these two tools you should be able to track down what is causing your problem, be it a permission issue, traffic blocking, etc.

Comment: I'm not trying to hit Central Administration.  I'm trying to get the web front end to return the main homepage...whether from RDPing into the server or from hitting it from my local PC accessing it via the ip address.

Comment: Gotcha, I misunderstood, I guess my previous response was not relevant at all. Edited.